# Java - Where does "class" method/field come from?

Tags: java, class, methods, field

Where does "class" method/field come from? I don't find any information about it in the API.

Code example:

```
public class SomeClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println(SomeClass.class);
    }    
}
```

Output: class SomeClass

Comment: It's defined in the language

Comment: What methods you are talking about?

Comment: class is a reserved keyword, so it cannot be the name of a field or a method. So it's the compiler that knows how to deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

This is "compiler magic" known as *Class Literals*:

> A class literal is an expression consisting of the name of a class, interface, array, or primitive type, or the pseudo-type void, followed by a `'.'` and the token `class` ([JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) 15.8.2)

In other words, although classes do not have a static member called `class`, the compiler behaves as if they did, inserting references to corresponding `Class` objects as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely true. This is from the [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html):

> It is also possible to get the Class object for a named type (or for
>   void) using a class literal. See [Section 15.8.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2) of The Java™ Language
>   Specification. For example:
>
> `System.out.println("The name of class Foo is: "+Foo.class.getName());`

So for more info you should just look at [Section 15.8.2 of The Java™ Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2).